# Disabling a menu item from another JFrame

Tags: java

am a junior and am a bit stuck. I have a log-in frame say JFrame1 that calls main window say JFrame2. I want some menu items disabled if not logged in as admin. I am using NetBeans IDE Any idea or code on how to go about it?

Comment: Seems like an Homework. What have you done/tried?

Comment: Do you mean `menuItem.setEnabled(false);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way (IMO) is to build a LoginPane (extends JPanel) component, and use JOptionPane to show it. Since JOptionPane regularly runs as a modal dialog, you can process the results in your main class after it has closed

```
LoginPane login = new LoginPane();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, login, "Please Enter Your Login Credentials", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
checkCredentials(login.getCredentials());
```